# What kind of standoffs work with this case?

Tags: motherboard, case, atx

I have a Chenbro PC61166 Xpider case which I got second hand.

The standouts for ATX mounting are missing, but where there would normally be screw holes for me to install common brass standoffs, there are rectangular holes (about 1/4" X 3/8").

[image: case interior]

I have to assume that there are some kind of clips that fill these holes, but my research has only turned up one reference to them, with no actionable advice. See [here](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=613841).

Could someone please help me identify the part, so I can look for it aftermarket?

Comment: http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2003/05/chenbropc610/1/ seems to be a review for the same case.

Comment: To add to what @JourneymanGeek said, this is on the website about the motherboard: "Motherboard installation requires the installation of thin metal standoffs into the case. There's no removable motherboard tray to aid in motherboard installation, but the whole process is reasonably painless. The only sticking point is that while installing the metal standoffs, you squeeze them into the mounting holes, then release them to lock them into place. "

Comment: Since you got it "secondhand" I'm assuming those pieces did not make it with the case when the first MOBO installed was pulled out. I think you're going to have to buy a new case. If you bought this from a local shop, I suggest taking it back for a full refund or asking them if they have the pieces required.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. if only that were an option. I'd really hate to have to spend on a case, especially since the required part probably costs less than a dollar (more to ship than purchase). If I just knew what to call them, theres a good chance I could find them online. quite frustrating.

Comment: Hah! Found it. As is, its a guessing game question - and I suspect the more crucial question is "What sort of standoff do I need with a case like this?" Any issues with rescoping the question?

Comment: no no, not at all. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was a complete and utter pain to find, but I managed to sniff it out.

Multiple sources [here](http://icrontic.com/article/build_pc_from_parts_software),[here](http://www.dansdata.com/homepc.htm) and [here](http://www.frozencpu.com/products/3508/scr-67/Professional_Hardware_Assortment_Pack_115_0250.html?tl=g4c157&id=NbzswVVs) call it a clip style standoff - the last of which is a vendor who sells it under the name.

More importantly icrontic has a good picture of one, so you can email your preferred parts vendor and get what you need,

[image]